# select repository url from github_timeline: group pushes and downloads by repos, and filter repos by stargazers

Tags: mysql, github, group-by, google-bigquery, group-concat

i don't know sql, i tried to document my self but could not achieve the result I want.

I am looking at this query on Bigquery, against Github_timeline:

```
SELECT repository_url, actor_attributes_login
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE type='WatchEvent' AND actor_attributes_login IN (
  SELECT actor_attributes_login FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
  WHERE type='WatchEvent'
  GROUP BY actor_attributes_login HAVING (count(*) > 1) AND (count (*) < 500)
)
GROUP EACH BY repository_url, actor_attributes_login;
```

found here: https://github.com/anvaka/ghindex

From my understanding, the query constraint results to repos with 1 < stargazers < 500.

I would like to:fetch data in one shot from multiple values of Type:
(for who's interesting, please find a description of types here: 
https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/)

I would like to:

- fetch data against other variable in Type field, e.g.pushEvents and downloadEvents
- group the pushes and downloads by repos: if a repo has multiple pushes from one user, return one line to reduce size of the resulting table.
- fetch number of stargazers for a project, with the limit 1

I tried to group lines by repository_url, followed by the stargazers with the limit 1

```
SELECT repository_url, actor_attributes_login, type
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE (type='PushEvent'OR type='WatchEvent') AND actor_attributes_login IN (
  SELECT repository_url, actor_attributes_login FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
  WHERE (type='WatchEvent' or type='PushEvent')
  GROUP BY repository_url, actor_attributes_login HAVING (count(*) > 1) AND (count (*) < 500) 
)
GROUP EACH BY repository_url, actor_attributes_login, type
LIMIT 100;
```

but got error:

```
Error: Right query in semi-join must have exactly one field selected.
```

I also tried to simplify and gather multiple variable from field TYPE, without attempt to group by repository_url; (here I only used AND actor_attributes_login=='author' to restrict number of results, as a test):

```
SELECT repository_url, actor_attributes_login, type
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE (type='WatchEvent') AND actor_attributes_login IN (
  SELECT actor_attributes_login FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
  WHERE (type='WatchEvent' OR type='PushEvent' OR type='DownloadEvent' OR type='IssueCommentEvent') AND actor_attributes_login=='author'
  GROUP BY actor_attributes_login HAVING (count(*) > 1) AND (count (*) < 500)
)
GROUP EACH BY repository_url, actor_attributes_login, type LIMIT 100;
```

But:

```
Query returned zero records.
```

Could you help in understanding what am I doing wrong, in order to:

- collect all pushes committed to repo from a user, into a unique row
- collect more events in Type field in one time (e.g. push + download + watch

Possibly I would like to combine the above queries the with the constraint applied to the number of users involved in a WatchEvent:
 - fetch all stars gazed to a repo (that is, all the actor_attributes_login in watchEvents), with a constraint to 1

But eventually I could do the last part in post-processing, to reduce complexity.
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I misunderstood your problem statement, but I think the following SQL will do what you want:

```
SELECT a.repository_url, a.actor_attributes_login, a.type
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline] a
JOIN EACH
(SELECT actor_attributes_login FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
 WHERE type IN ('WatchEvent', 'PushEvent')
 GROUP BY actor_attributes_login HAVING (count(*) BETWEEN 1 AND 500)
) b
ON a.actor_attributes_login = b.actor_attributes_login
GROUP EACH BY 1,2,3 LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: hi @MoshaPasumansky, thank you for your answer.
Could you help in break the query in pieces to understand what it does?
What's the meaning of 'join each' and the syntax 'on  a.attributes = b.attributes' ?
Could you explain the logic of using a 'join' respect the original one which does not use it (see the one posted in ghindex) ?
I run it and it look to fetch all events in _a_type_ field, not only 'WatchEvent' and 'PushEvent'. Thank you!

Comment: The IN clause in your original query was fine semantically, but it has hit scalability limitation, hence I had to change it to JOIN EACH. The "EACH" part is a hint to use more expensive, but more scalable execution, and this hint is only available for JOIN clause, not for IN clause. If you need to restrict a.type the same way b.type is restricted, use the same WHERE type IN ('WatchEvent', 'PushEvent') clause on the left side of JOIN.

Comment: I don't understand the WHERE restriction here. I thought your query fetched only "watchevent" and "pushevents" actors took part in, for each repo.
With `WHERE type='WatchEvent' AND actor_attributes_login IN (
  SELECT actor_attributes_login FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
  WHERE type='WatchEvent'` it will return all actors who contributed to WatchEvent, while `SELECT actor_attributes_login FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
 WHERE type IN ('WatchEvent', 'PushEvent')` apparently return all events actors contributed to, not only 'WatchEvent' or 'PushEvent'. Could you please explain why?

Comment: Here is query to verify that WHERE clause worked correctly: ``SELECT type, count(*) FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline] WHERE type IN ('WatchEvent', 'PushEvent') group by 1``. Why do you think you are getting all types ?

Comment: I think I am getting all types because in the resoults i get things like: 
`21 https://github.com/marina-zhezhel/portfolio marina-zhezhel CreateEvent  
22 https://github.com/bellkev/BodyMation bellkev PublicEvent  
23 https://github.com/grmcom/TouchLive blister75 ForkEvent  
24 https://github.com/pepelazz/KinevskayaSite pepelazz DeleteEvent  
25 https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate CassiusPacheco WatchEvent`, not only WatchEvent and PushEvent. Am I misunderstanding the Where clause maybe?